# ANTLR4 predicates with greedy * quantifier: avoid unnecessary predicate calls (lexing)

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Following lexer grammar snippet is supposed to tokenize 'custom names' depending on a predicate that is defined in a class `LexerHelper`:

```
fragment NUMERICAL      : [0-9];

fragment XML_NameStartChar
                        : [:a-zA-Z]
                        | '\u2070'..'\u218F'
                        | '\u2C00'..'\u2FEF'
                        | '\u3001'..'\uD7FF'
                        | '\uF900'..'\uFDCF'
                        | '\uFDF0'..'\uFFFD'
                        ;

fragment XML_NameChar   : XML_NameStartChar
                        | '-' | '_' | '.' | NUMERICAL
                        | '\u00B7'
                        | '\u0300'..'\u036F'
                        | '\u203F'..'\u2040'
                        ;

fragment XML_NAME_FRAG  : XML_NameStartChar XML_NameChar*;

CUSTOM_NAME             : XML_NAME_FRAG ':' XML_NAME_FRAG {LexerHelper.myPredicate(getText())}?;
```

The correct match for CUSTOM_NAME is always the longest possible match. Now if the lexer encounters a custom name such as `some:cname` then I would like it to lex the entire string `some:cname` and then call the predicate once with 'some:cname' as argument.

Instead, the lexer calls the predicate with each possible 'valid' match it finds along the way, so `some:c`, `some:cn`, `some:cna`, `some:cnam` until finally `some:cname`.

Is there a way to change the behaviour to force antlr4 to first find the longest possible match, before calling the predicate? Alternatively, is there an efficient way for the predicate to determine that the match is not the longest one yet to simply return with `false` in that case?

EDIT: The funny thing about this behavior is that as long as only partial matches are passed to the predicate, the result of the predicate seems to be completely ignored by the lexer anyway. This seems oddly inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the behavior is known and permitted by Antlr. Antlr may or may not call predicates more than necessary ([see here for more details](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2578#issuecomment-503532266)). To avoid that behavior I am now using actions instead, which only get executed once the rule has completely and successfully matched. This allows me to e.g. switch modes in an action.

Comment: Don't forget it must be possible to have a predicate which succeeds or fails based on the length of the input, which is a valid scenario. This can only be implemented by executing the predicate each time a char was matched. Inefficient? Yes, but if that matters to you don't use predicates in the first place, but check certain syntactic and semantic aspects after the parse run.

Comment: What's wrong with simply useing 'getText().length' to check the input length?



Unfortunately waiting until after parsing is complete is not always possible, as code may sometimes need to be parsed/lexed differently, depending on some external variables that the lexer/parser doesn't know during compile time. As in 'generate an entirely different tree', at which point the decision needs to be made during lexing/parsing.